# Instagram API: get all media and sort by date created asc

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

According to the Instagram API endpoints, we could do this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But the above query returns the most recent media posted by a user. Now I want to sort the result by created date ascending. Does this API has this feature? or I have to go through pagination way and sort it after?

Answer (score 3):

There is no API param to sort by date ascending, you have to do it manually by getting all posts using pagination and then flip the order.